# Build a SETUP that installs 2 applications and 3 runtimes

Tags: c#

**Work on VS08 C# window** .**Client have not .Net environment** . I have 2 setup files - applications and 3 runtimes .net, vstor&InteI will need 1 Setup file that will contain and install automatically the following

```
I will need 1 Setup file that will contain and install automatically the following
1. o2007pia
2. dotnetfx35setup
3. vstor30
4. MT4Api
5. Mexcel Trader4
rlop assembly. I would usually have to click on each and install them separately.
```

I will need create a single SETUP file that would automatically install all the other setups.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .Net 2008 Setup Project will let you specify multiple projects outputs for your installer (right click on your setup project, then click Add->Project Output), and I think it also allows you to automatically check for and install the .Net framework ([msdn instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480173.aspx)).  This is done through the setup project's Properties->Prerequisites, then you check the prerequisites you want to be installed with your program.